# Как объявить собственный базовый тип (или его аналог) в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, типы-данных

В проекте, мне приходится работать с разными по смыслу значениями, многие из которых имеют один и тот же тип - Integer. И получается, что достаточно легко перепутать и присвоить значение одного смыслового типа - другому. К сожалению, использовать enum не получится, т.к. значения имеют большой диапазон (`-MaxInt..MaxInt`).

Для упрощения разработки, мне бы хотелось объявлять собственные тип, несовместимые с другими простыми типами.

Например:

```
type
  TMySingle = Single;

var
  A: TMySingle;
  B: Single;
begin
  A := 0.0; // ошибка
  A := TMySingle(0.0); // допустимо
  A := B; // ошибка
  A := TMySingle(B);// допустимо
```

То есть я бы хотел получить что-то аналогичное тому как взаимодействуют Integer и String - прямое присвоение невозможно, а только через явное преобразование (`IntToStr` и `StrToInt`)

Как такое сделать в Delphi? Или что-то подобное?

Comment: Добавить к своему типу implicit/explicit operator: [Operator Overloading](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi))

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это же вроде только к `record` относится, или уже есть возможности и у простых типов так делать? С `record` есть опасения, что просядет производительность - часть работы достаточно ресурсоемкая.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica Можете тогда использовать условную компиляцию: для дебажной версии определить тип как `record` (с методами явного приведения), а для релизной как `Integer`.

Answer (score 4):

Кое-что можно сделать через [перегрузку операторов](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)) для записей. Я не объявил `Implicit`, поэтому прямые присвоения невозможны.  Базовую арифметику для нового типа также описать можно, чтобы это выглядело обычным образом, а вот, скажем, `Sqrt` - уже нет.

```
  TMySingle = record
    S: Single;
    class operator Explicit(A: TMySingle): Single;
    class operator Explicit(B: Single): TMySingle;
  end;

class operator TMySingle.Explicit(B: Single): TMySingle;
begin
  Result.S := B;
end;

class operator TMySingle.Explicit(A: TMySingle): Single;
begin
  Result := A.S;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button30Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TMySingle;
  b: Single;
begin
  a := TmySingle(3.0);
  b := Single(A);
  Caption := b.ToString;
//  b := a;  нельзя
//  a := b;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Для этого существует недокументированная конструкция **type of**:

```
program types;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TMySingle = type of Single;

var
  A: TMySingle;
  B: Single;
begin
  try
    A := 0.0; // можно
    B := 0.0; // можно
    B := Single(A); // можно
    A := TMySingle(B);  // можно
    B := A; // Incompatible types: 'Single' and 'TMySingle'
    A := TMySingle(0.0); // E2089 Invalid typecast
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

> Поскольку этого нет в документации - вы будете использовать это на
>   свой страх и риск. Отсутствие ошибок, неоднозначного поведения и
>   совместимости с будущими версиями дельфи не гарантируются.

Comment: Не знаю насчёт документации, привёл полный код проекта в котором я только что протестировал эту конструкцию в Delphi 10.3. Без двух последних строчек всё компилируется, с ними - выдаёт указанные ошибки. Если верить [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555272/what-type-of-declaration-represents-in-delphi-and-how-can-it-be-used) то это недокументированная функция (для бага она живёт слишком долго, компилятор вроде поменялся с 14 года).

Comment: Угу, `TMySingle(B);` срабатывает, а как было `TMySingle(0.0);` - нет. Не знаю, как к этому относиться - вот недокументированные псевдоконструкторы дин.массивов в 2006 кто-то обнаружил `TMyArr.Create(1,2,3)`  вместо многострочного задания- и оно всегда работало, уже не ломали.

Comment: @MBo, Сейчас TMyArr.Create() - это официально [документированная](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) функция, хотя возможно во времена Delphi 2006 в справке их не было.

Comment: Всё верно. Будет ли третий вид эквивалентности (кроме `MyInt=Int, MyInt = type Int`)официально введен - указаний пока не видно